# Aligning text on the same line with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been struggling with how to align these two items. As you can see if you run the code snippet, the 'Newsletter' is a tad bit lower than the 'Resources'. Both are supposed to be vertically and horizontally aligned but for some reason, they are not on the same line.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #6D7B8D;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
 <footer>
   <div class="footer">

     <div class="col">
       <p class="coltitle">Resources</p>
       <ul class="footer-links">
         <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>

     <div class="col">
       <p class="coltitle">Newletter</p>
       <ul class="footer-links">
         <li>
           <form action="#" method="post">
             <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Subscribe" maxlength="80" required />
           </form>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>

   </div>
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the `align-items: center` and added a `margin-top` to `.col`, does that work for you?

```css
 * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }


    .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: #6D7B8D;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .col {
    margin-top: 30px;
    }
```

```html
 <footer>
   <div class="footer">

     <div class="col">
       <p class="coltitle">Resources</p>
       <ul class="footer-links">
         <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>

     <div class="col">
       <p class="coltitle">Newletter</p>
       <ul class="footer-links">
         <li>
           <form action="#" method="post">
             <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Subscribe" maxlength="80" required />
           </form>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>

   </div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly works! I hadn't considered it before!